# When searching for a file from the Windows 7 Start Menue, how can I restrict the list of results to those containing the search item in the filename?

Tags: windows-7, search

When I am looking for an answer to the question "Where is file XYZ?" and use the search function from the Start Menu, the result contains the desired files where "XYZ" is part of the filename, but also the files where "XYZ" is found in the file content.

Since the latter is not needed in my search, how can I exclude them from the list of results?

Comment: Which Windows version are you using ?

Comment: @n_stan: Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the search term with `name:` to restrict it.
There are also other specifiers possible, like `datemodified:` or `size:`.
A description of this syntax can be found at [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx), even though this page purports to be obsolete after Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you. This helps, but "name:R.dll" finds "RSAENH.dll.bi".